# pip -r error at in bash script

Tags: python, bash, pip, python-2.x

```
#!/bin/bash -e
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

when I execute above script I get below error message;

```
 Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 173, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 71, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2593, in parse_requirements
    raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '\xe2\x80\x93r')

Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

But if I execute

```
pip install –r  requirements.txt
```

directly by bash, it works fine. what could be the reason?

Below are the python and pip version I have;

```
user@ubuntu:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.6
user@ubuntu:~$ pip -V
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: What's in `requirements.txt` vs `env_requirements.txt`?

Comment: is `requirements.txt` accessible within the script's executing env, specifically either in current dir or `$PATH`

Comment: sorry fo the confussion. I have updated question. "requirements.txt" is being used for both commands. I have put file "requirements.txt" in same directory with script but its still not working

Comment: Do you need the `-e` in the shebang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\xe2\x80\x93
```

That's a UTF-8 encoded [en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). Be sure to use the usual (ASCII) [dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm).

In other words, replace this:

```
pip install –r requirements.txt
```

with this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it resolved my issue. I guess it was happeing since I have copied it from somewhere else.